How to type hint `**kwargs` inside a dataclass?
I have a class like this with field members consisting of different types, and inside my class I have __new__(cls, **kwargs) and I would like to type hint **kwargs.
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class Foo
    var1: int
    var2: float
    var3: bool
    var4: str
    var5: Optional[list[float]]

    def __new__(cls, **kwargs) -> "Foo":
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)

I ideally want to be able to do something like:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional
from typing_extensions import Unpack

@dataclass
class Foo
    var1: int
    var2: float
    var3: bool
    var4: str
    var5: Optional[list[float]]

    def __new__(cls, **kwargs: Unpack[Foo]) -> "Foo":
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)

But referencing Foo within __new__ isn't possible.

Do the answers to this question help at all?

You can't Unpack a dataclass. Just use a TypedDict, it's longer, but I'd wager it's the best you're going to get. overriding __new__ is uncommon enough that you can expect less ergonomics.
class FooArgs(TypedDict):
    var1: int
    var2: float
    var3: bool
    var4: str
    var5: Optional[list[float]]


@dataclass
class Foo
    var1: int
    var2: float
    var3: bool
    var4: str
    var5: Optional[list[float]]

    def __new__(cls, **kwargs: Unpack[FooArgs]) -> "Foo":
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)

